# Is it possible to pass a property as a ref parameter in a setter? c# (avoid "a property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter".)

Tags: c#, properties

I have this code:

```
private int _someProperty;
public int SomeProperty
{
    get => _someProperty;
    set => SetProperty(ref _someProperty, value);
}

private void SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value)
{
    if (!field.Equals(value))
    {
        field = value;
    }
}
```

I need the `SetProperty<T>` because I need a set logic in a big class with lots of properties, and that logic applies to all of them.
The code works for the case of `_someProperty`being a variable. But in my case, it does not work because I reference to another property of a nested class, so I get the compilation error: "a property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter".

As properties are methods under the hood, I tried something like:

```
private setProperty<T>(ref Action<T> property, T value) {
    //meaningful code
}
```

But I get the compilatuion error anyhow.

Is there a direct way to pass a property by reference to directly solve this problem somehow?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316417/1997232) implementation.

Comment: very useful, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, basically.

There *is* a potential loophole around mutable ref-returning get-only properties, but that probably won't help you because:

1. you *can't have any set logic* in a mutable ref-returning get-only property
2. this is an absurdly niche scenario that the majority of devs *don't know exists, and will never need to use* :)

Comment: @TheGeneral just be warned: you cannot unsee. At your choice: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/c46a1de553abe325dea0c44ac7fa7766 - note, this isn't the usual usage of this language feature, as in this case it is pretty much the same as exposing the field directly. A more typical usage might be for a flyweight, or to provide controlled access (by-ref) to values inside an array/etc; if it had existed at the time, `ArraySegment<T>` could have had an indexer `public ref T this[int index] => ref Array[Offset + index];`, for example

Comment: @TheGeneral what's *really* fun; did you know that there's actually a `foreach` syntax for custom iterators that have ref-return of `.Current`, that allows you to mutate the foreach iteration variable (usually raises CS1656)? https://gist.github.com/mgravell/db3e63c2f8cea1866a6aaade7507fa18

Comment: hah cool, that's fairly intersting. If I could upvote again I would

Comment: You could do an adults-only after dark blog for c#, that second one seems like a one way street to Benign error town. I like it though!